# put custom ssh public key into authorized_keys on minikube cluster

Tags: minikube

How to put a custom ssh public key into `authorized_keys` on minikube cluster? Why the changes to `/home/docker/.ssh/authorized_keys` lose after reboot? How to edit this file effectively?

Answer (score 5):

This works (minikube v1.2.0):

```sh
minikube ssh

cd /var/lib/boot2docker
sudo cp userdata.tar userdata-backup.tar

cd /home/docker
echo YOUR_SSH_PUBLIC_KEY_HERE >> .ssh/authorized_keys
sudo tar cf /var/lib/boot2docker/userdata.tar .
```

because of minikube extract files from userdata.tar at boot, and the [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/deploy/iso/minikube-iso/package/automount/minikube-automount#L136) is here.